# How can I convert a grayscale video to RGB (jet colormap) in C# or Python?

Tags: python, c#, encoding, video-processing

I have a grayscale video that I'd like to convert and process to RGB using a jet colormap. Currently I'm pulling all of the frames out of the video using FFMPEG, locking the byte array of pixel data from each frame, pulling the pixels out and converting them to 8bit RGB using some mapping to a jet colormap and then streaming the new bitmaps to a video using FFMPEG.

The code is all in C# and works well enough, my issue is that with videos that have more than 2,000 frames or so it gets VERY slow.

Is there any efficient way that I can do what I'm attempting in either python or C#? Or do I need to venture into the world of GPU programming and shaders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is un-answerable as a **programming question**. **(1)** Is it slow because that's your system speed (based on your output settings like resolution and quality) or have you seen other software effect & encode same 2000 frames faster on your same computer? **(2)** Is it the C# pixel effecting that is slow? Then consider GPU, or else is it the FFmpeg encoding that is slow? Consider using lower resolution for quick previews and accept the long wait for the final output...

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it in Python, though I'm not sure about efficiency. It should be reasonably quick, though, as many big Python libraries are just wrappers for C++ libraries. OpenCV (aka cv2) is no exception, and color mapping with it in Python is super easy:

```py
import cv2

# Read grayscale images and store as raw 2D arrays (hxw) in gray_images list
gray_images = [...]

for im_gray in gray_images:
    im_color = cv2.applyColorMap(im_gray, cv2.COLORMAP_JET) # im_color = 3D (hxwx3) BGR image
```

See [this](https://learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python/) webpage for more details.